# AngularJS Add Multiple Objects to Object Literal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

When I click "Evan" I get:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Evan"}
```

When I click "Robert" I get:

```
{"id":2,"name":"Robert"}
```

How can I modify this code to follow the above steps and get an object like this (**not an array**):

```
{"id":1,"name":"Evan"},
{"id":2,"name":"Robert"}
```

Here's my Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/EkKlx7cJG8L0IkRTY6dU?p=preview

Here's my view:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="select(item)">
        {{item.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p ng-show="selected">{{selected}}</p>
  </body>
```

Here's my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Evan"

        },
        "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Robert"

        },
        "3": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Justin"
        }
    }
  $scope.selected = {};
    $scope.select = function (item) {
    $scope.selected = item;
    }
});
```

Comment: You cannot get in that format itself as it is invalid. You could however get `{"1":"Evan", "2":"Robert"}` by doing `$scope.selected[item.id] = item.name;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply a key for the intended value inside your `selected` object.

If you're opposed to an array, I'd suggest you modify the select function as such:

```
$scope.select = function (item) {
  $scope.selected[item.id] = item;
};
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LeIrQ7vcK9WuuYAJ1C2A?p=preview)

Comment: Happy that works for you. I'll go ahead and shamelessly ask that you accept the given answer.

Comment: Done. SO has a 15 minute delay before an answer can be accepted, which is why I didn't do this on Friday. Thanks again.